# how to add jquery to jasmine

Tags: jquery, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined


error properties: Object({ ngDebugContext: DebugContext_({ view: Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 33669121, rootNodeFlags: 33554433, nodeMatchedQueries: 0, flags: 0, nodes: [ Object({ nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 33554433, childFlags: 114688, directChildFlags: 114688, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object({  }), matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object({  }), ngContentIndex: null, childCount: 1, bindings: [  ], bindingFlags: 0, outputs: [  ], element: Object({ ns: '', name: 'app-asignacion', attrs: [  ], template: null, componentProvider: Object({ nodeIndex: 1, parent: <circular reference: Object>, renderParent: <circular reference: Object>, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 1, flags: 114688, childFlags: 0, directChildFlags: 0, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object, matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object, ngContentIndex: -1, childCount: 0, bindings: Array, bindingFlags: 0, outputs:  ...
at <Jasmine>
at AsignacionComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:6206:5)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:31910:1)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:44367:1)
at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:44306:1)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:45328:36)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:45271:1)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///DynamicTestModule/AsignacionComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:10:5)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:45259:1)
at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:44271:1)
at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:45632:1)
```

I try add the path to jquery in the karma.conf.js but the problem persists

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

files: [
  'node_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js',     
],

//rest karma options
 });
};
```

somebody help me?

thank you!!!

Comment: This is one of the **many** reasons why mixing jquery and angular is a really bad idea. jquery is just going to mess up your unit tests. You shouldn't be using it at all

Comment: I don't decide if I have to use it. I just have to create the test cases.  How to solve this?

Comment: Contact whoever wrote the software and tell them that the test cases have failed because they're using jquery...

Comment: That's the solution, really?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those people who have the same problem in the future and receive the same help that I received in this post.

just add in karma.conf.js

```
files:[
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```